# Full list of top-like tool family for perfomance monitoring in linux: iftop iotop htop atop more?

Tags: linux, top, io

Top-like utilities are extremely handful in my work and I want to make sure I am not missing any of them. Please extend the following list of performance monitoring (top-like) family of linux tools:

- top - original tool
- htop - adds support to multicore/cpu
- iotop - input/output monitoring
- iftop - network monitoring
- atop - merges previous elements into a single overview
- gtop - fancy [visuals](https://github.com/aksakalli/gtop) of system stats
- slabtop – displays a listing of the top caches
- ?

The only criteria - maturity and similarity in function/style.

Comment: RAM monitoring?

Comment: One more great question closed by SO "power users".

Comment: @alexander-g Yes, because this would be better on a wiki where it can be edited over time.

Comment: How do we convert the post to a community wiki post? It's very useful.

Answer (score 8):

[nethogs](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/) - Bandwidth Monitoring by Process